# Custom redirect to an url with "+"

Tags: 8, forms, search

I use [search api module](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and a view of products. If I put the search text block and I do a search, It redirect to an url like this: 
 `<my domain>?search_api_fulltext=word1+word2+word3&sort_by=title_1&sort_order=ASC`

Where all search words are separated by a plus sign ("+").
I have my custom search block and I want to redirect to the same url in the submit function of the form. This is my code:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

if (!empty($form_state->getValue('textBox'))) {      
  $text = str_replace(' ', '+', $form_state->getValue('textBox'));
  $option = [
    'query' => ['search_api_fulltext' => $text, 
                'sort_by'=>'search_api_relevance', 
                'sort_order'=>'ASC'],
  ];
  $url = Url::fromUri('internal:/shop', $option);
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);      
}
return;
```

}

But it redirect to `<my domain>?search_api_fulltext=word1%2Bword2&sort_by=title_1&sort_order=ASC`, where plus signs are replaced with %2B, and then, the search is incorrect.
How could I avoid this replacement?

Comment: I suspect you need to pass an array for multiple values, instead of creating the string as you are. Try changing this `$text = str_replace(' ', '+', $form_state->getValue('textBox'));` to `$text = explode(' ', $form_state->getValue('textBox'));`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you're building is taking the query (e.g. `"word1 word2 word3"`) and replacing it with literal `"+"` chars for spaces. Hence, the `%2B` encoding in the string.

You don't need to parse/encode `$form_state->getValue('textBox')`. Per the documentation of [`Url::fromUri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.2.x) for the `$options` param:

> - 'query': An array of query key/value-pairs (**without any URL-encoding**) to append to the URL.

`$options['query']` expects its key/value pairs to have the literal strings.

You needn't worry about `+`/`%20` encoding differences. They are different ways to encode the space character. (the `+` is an older space-encoding spec which you can do if absolutely needed, see `rawurlencode`, `urlencode`, & `http_build_query` in the PHP docs).